# Get PSObject properties as string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse the output of a PowerShell command (`Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics`): `EntityId` and `FolderId` fields are displayed as strings in the output but if I try to access them, they are displayed as array of bytes. How can I prevent this behavior?

[image: output of the commands]

Comment: Likely a `ScriptProperty`, if you do `(Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics)[0] | Get-Member EntryId | Select-Object -Expand Definition` do you see anything?

Comment: to see the type of all properties, use: `Get-Member -InputObject (Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics)`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i'm getting this output

Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.EntryId {get;set;}